# How scanf function works in C?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a, b;
    printf("Enter the values of a and b");
    scanf(" %d%d ", &a, &b);
    printf("a=%d b=%d", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Why do we have to insert 3 inputs as spaces are given before and after the double quotes?

Comment: @chqrlie, why has he to accept one answer? probably none of them satisfies.  Don't ask for it, that's not polite.

Comment: @LuisColorado: The OP has very little experience on SO, I am just telling how to accept an answer. His question was fully addressed in both answers, accepting one of them is the expected behavior.  I shall rephrase the comment to make it more neutral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `scanf()` format `" %d%d "` has extra spaces with undesired side-effects:

- the first one is redundant, it instructs `scanf()` to skip any leading whitespace, but it does so already as part of the `%d` conversion.  Remove it.
- the trailing one is causing your problem: it tells `scanf()` to skip any trailing whitespace after the second integer. It therefore keeps reading input until it sees something thatis not whitespace or the end of the stream.  Remove it too.

Note that you should also verify that `scanf()` did convert 2 integers before using their values.  Also always print a trailing newline as some systems do not flush output properly if you don't.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a, b;
    printf("Enter the values of a and b: ");
    if (scanf("%d%d", &a, &b) == 2) {
        printf("a=%d b=%d\n", a, b);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why do we have to insert 3 inputs as spaces are given before and after the double quotes?

When you have a *whitespace* in the format string, it'll skip any number of whitespaces in the input stream. So, `scanf()` expects a non-whitespace* input in order to terminate.

From [scanf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) manual:

> A sequence of white-space characters (space, tab, newline etc.; see
>   isspace(3)).  This directive matches any amount of white space,
>   including none, in the input.

So, remove the whitespaces from the format string. Or better, [avoid scanf() altogether.](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html)